# Paypal SDK is not working for INR currency

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I have developed mobile app using Ionic 3. I have added Paypal sdk payment integration in my app. It worked  fine for USD currency. But its not working for INR. I am getting this error.

> main.js:1 Error or render dialog closed without being successful
>   payment not processable

Please, help me to fix this error.

Code:

```
this.payment = new PayPalPayment('1', 'INR', 'sale', 'TV');

this.payPal.init({
        PayPalEnvironmentProduction: '',
        PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'token'
    }).then(() => {
        this.payPal.prepareToRender(this.payPalEnvironment, new PayPalConfiguration({})).then(() => {
            this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(this.payment).then((response) => {
      // alert(`Successfully paid. Status = ${response.response.state}`);

            }, (err) => {
                console.error('Error or render dialog closed without being successful', err);
            });
        }, () => {
            console.error('Error in configuration');
        });
    }, () => {
        console.error('Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn\'t supported or something else');
    });
```

Thanks in advance !!!